# Статическое выделение памяти, Java

Tags: java

Как в Java статические выделить память под массив? (нужно создать копию заданной матрицы, а то, если выделить память динамически, получается, по сути, 2 ссылки на одну матрицу и если изменить дну, изменится и другая)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java